# Alcohol and gym gains

Tags: weightlifting, muscle, weight-gain, alcohol, strength-gain

I am 19 and looking to build muscle and strength for joining the RAF. I attempt to go to the gym three times a week: Sunday, Monday, Wednesday, and obviously as being 19 I love my social life and going out Friday to drink and dance. Now I was wondering if it is worth going to the gym on a Thursday as well? Will the alcohol, and poor sleep the next night just make it pointless any advice would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not it is benefitial for you to train an additional night depends on your goals. Training the extra night could work out fine, the alcohol and less sleep on friday night will make the recovery process longer though.

Your liver is key in this. Your liver does a lot of things that a essential when you work out a lot (such as metabolising amino acids and converting excess carbohydrates and proteins into fatty acids and triglyceride), and this is be restricted when you consume alcohol because your liver will start working on breaking that down instead.

This means that you could still notice some soreness even during the sunday training.

Answer (score 2):

Alcohol, poor sleep is against your training anyway. So one more, or less - is not much change anyway. Note that every well done training is better then sitting at home, even if you would not take 100% of it.

Moving from obvious to less obvious things.

Usually people decide not to drink, but that works for older... Young people, like you... Heh - please take care, and do things properly, keep yourself far from injury. Just train. I'm a bit jealous seeing young people training, and their progress. But there is one potential problems - it is quite easy to get injured, and that will stay with you... Note that you are training for particular reason, not to take more then others. Just slowly progress, no shortcuts are here, and potential fast forward can lead to serious problems.

Please ask another questions about your goals, describing what is your plan, maybe that way someone can better help you.